# Verilog project - Binary to BCD - 0-49 2 digit display

Tags: verilog, logic-gates, 7segmentdisplay, binary

I have an end of the year project where I must create an 4 operation ALU that outputs its result onto 7 segment displays in Verilog.

2 of those operations are multiplication and addition. Considering each input is 3 bits, I can achieve a max number of 49 (7x7).

I originally created a binary to BCD converter, using the double dabble algorithm with the iterations being triggered by the clock cycle. My project was running and I got into the report and ran into a major issue.

Our project must show from the top level blocks all the way down to the **gate level**

I spoke to my professor about this and he informed me that my method of using the double dabble algorithm is too complex for this project as we need to show the gate level of our design.

I'm somewhat stumped on where to go from here. A majority of other students are using a case statement with 49 options for each display (0-49, where the ones column shows 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3... and the tens column shows 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1....) I don't see how this would simplify things in terms of design using logic gates, however, maybe I'm wrong?

Can someone shed some light onto a possible route I could take with this?

Comment: What are the two other operations you need to support?

Comment: You have 8 input bits (3 bits each for operand A and B, and 2 bits to select 1 of 4 opcodes), and 14 outputs: 7 for each segment, 16 if you include the decimal points. Although it’s unlikely to satisfy your professor because it requires no Verilog skills, the solution with the fewest gates (zero) would be to use a single block RAM configured as a big ROM lookup table. Spartan’s 512k x 36 BRAM would accommodate 9 input bits and 36 outputs, so for “free” you could another input bit (e.g. 3rd opcode bit, on/off, dec/hex) and more outputs (operands on two 7-segments, operator with 4 discrete LEDs)

Comment: (@td127 `Spartan’s 512k` contains one k too much for *9 input bits*.)

Comment: Above 9+9=18, a table will contain a lot of unreachable results/don't cares. `I don't see how [any given way of specifying a bundle of functions] would simplify things` ideally, all of them should be equivalent. But specifying 50 values where 28 are possible isn't. (49 would skip at least one value, just as the run of zeroes for "the tens column" is one too short.)